# SkypeForBusiness Desktop Sharing on UCMA 5.0

Tags: c#, lync-2013, ucma, skype-for-business, desktop-sharing

I have a UCMA 4.0 program, handles IM calls supports Application Sharing. It always worked fine for me on Lync 2013 conversations.
Recently I upgraded my program to UCMA 5.0, using Skype for Business instead of Lync 2013.

Strangely, since I did, Application Sharing doesn't work for me anymore.
The moment I confirm the Desktop Sharing action – I get this error:
**"Screen presenting isn't supported with this contact."** , at the bottom of the conversation window.

My code is :

```
endpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<ApplicationSharingCall>(ApplicationSharingCall_Received);
```

Good scenario is: once I confirm the Desktop Sharing action - ApplicationSharingCall_Received event is raised.

Trying to debug it, I realized that no matter what I do, the breakpoint on this event is never hitted, in contrast to the old version.

It seems like I miss some changes between Lync 2013 to SFB version.
Is there any other event I've never heared about?
Does anyone have any other suggestion for me?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do have a suggestion.  Keep using UCMA 4.0.  I have never seen a compelling reason to use UCMA 5.0 myself.  UCMA 4.0 apps work fine on SFB.